# bunzip2 doesn't decompress Wikipedia dump

Tags: terminal

I've downloaded a `.bz2` wikipedia dump (19GB) to my 2TB USB hard drive and want to decompress (wiki says it should be about 80GB uncompressed) it using `bunzip2` via the terminal on my pi 3B+ (64-bit SoC @ 1.4GHz and 1GB LPDDR2 SDRAM), but when I try, nothing seems to happen ever after waiting a long time.  I tried last night and let it run for about 2.5 hours and when I came back, there was still no result or error or anything.

While it doesn't specify the processor frequency or machine in general, [this](https://superuser.com/a/1171526/1024462) post suggests it should take around only 30 seconds.  That post also suggests using a multithreaded variation of the command, but I'm skeptical of doing that on the pi in case of overheating and memory usage.

I've tried simply using `bunzip2` and also trying to get a progress monitor using `pv`

[image]

[image]

but both are met with just the cursor moving to the new line and nothing continuing to happen; text is even still able to be entered.  In the case of using `pv`, the progress bar only comes up after entering a `^C`.

I've tried looking around but can't seem to find anyone else that's had this problem.  Do I just need to wait longer, or is there something I'm missing?  Or is this even feasible to do on the pi?

Answer (score 1):

With such a slow speed, I would check if your HDD is writable at all. Perhaps it's full of badblocks pending relocation, and writing new data is essentially stalled.

Also for a single compressed file you could add a progress bar for `bunzip2` output, rather than input, though I don't think it will help:

```
bunzip2 file.xml.bz2 | pv -s 80G > file.xml
```